# Tiny mce get content with php

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

Hello I want to use Tiny mce editor and i want to take the text typed by the user and insert it in a database ca n anyone tell me how i would achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE typically replaces a standard form textarea - so on form submission, the textarea contents would be available to you via the standard $_POST array (e.g. $_POST['my_texarea']). You can then validate the contents and do your database insert.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you should call `editor.triggerSave();` on one of the editor instances on your page.
This will update each elements for which a tinymce editor instance have been created.
Now, you can use an ajax call to send the html elements innerHTML to a remote php script where you can save the content to a db:

```
var content_to_be_send_using_ajax = $('#my_tinymce_htlm_element_id').innerHTML; // might be a textarea, a div or anything else
// now send it here to your php script
```

Another option is to use the [saveplugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3asave). When the save action is performed the form that the editor is within gets submitted.